numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Matrix is singular to machine precision
I'm trying to use bai-perron code from https://github.com/ceholden/pybreakpoints repo.
My python version is 3.12.2
The code I wrote is similar to their test.
    from pybreakpoints.baiperron import breakpoint
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    
    nile = pd.read_csv("tests/data/nile.csv")
    X = np.ones_like(nile)
    results = breakpoint(X, nile)

But I got errors.
mytest.py", line 9, in <module>
    results = breakpoint(X, nile)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
\pybreakpoints\baiperron.py", line 76, in breakpoint
    ssr = recresid(X_[i:n, :], y_[i:n])
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
\pybreakpoints\recresid_.py", line 134, in recresid
    rresid = _recresid(_X, _y, span)[span:]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

\Python312\Lib\site-packages\numba\np\linalg.py", line 899, in _inv_err_handler
    raise np.linalg.LinAlgError(
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Matrix is singular to machine precision.

Since it is the data from the repo the test should at least be able to run. I suspect this is just data format problem but I'm new to python and not sure how to debug.

The git repo you linked shows the package hasn't been updated for 6 years...

@jared unfortunately there aren't alternatives or I haven't found one.

Something internally is probably using a normal matrix inverse where it was previously using a pseudo-inverse.  The latter can handle singular matrices (badly, but depending on the algorithm recovery might be possible) while the former can't.

Tried hunting that particular error message down in numpy to see of I could use it as a signpost for a version and "Matrix is singular to machine precision" doesn't seem to be anywhere - it should be "Matrix is singular" in every version I see, even the newest dev versions.  If there's a better singularity check going on somewhere (np.linalg.inv - which is called by pybreakpoints - notes that ill-conditioned matrices can slip by the singularity check) it might be the case that the a tighter singularity check is catching matrices that previously worked.

That better singularity check would need to be coming from a third package overwriting numpy error-checking definitions though.
